# Repeat email function

Tags: javascript, html, email

I have a function that checks to make sure people correctly enter their email.

I got the code from here.
[Repeat email in HTML Form not the same. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687776/repeat-email-in-html-form-not-the-same-why)

The problem is if you enter your email incorrectly in the second input "eMail_repeat" you can change the second input no problem. But if you enter it incorrectly in the first input "eMail" and correctly in the second, then try change the first, it still shows as the emails dont match.

Any Ideas?

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="formmail.php" name="form" width="100%">


<fieldset> <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="confquest">

<tr height="80px"><td><label for="eMail" id="emaillabel"><strong>Email address:</strong></label><br> <input id="eMail" type="email" name="EmailAddr" title="Enter your email address" placeholder="example@mail.com" required /></td></tr>

<tr height="80px"><td><label for"eMail_repeat" id="emaillabel2"><strong>Repeat Email address:</strong></label><br> <input id="eMail_repeat" type="email" name="email_addr_repeat" title="Repeat your email address" placeholder="example@mail.com" required oninput="check(this)" /></td></tr> </table>


<input id="submit2" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</fieldset></form>


<script> 
   function check(input) { 
   if (input.value != document.getElementById('eMail').value) { 
   input.setCustomValidity('The two email addresses must match.'); 
   } else { 
    // input is valid -- reset the error message 
   input.setCustomValidity(''); 
  } 
  } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your second input you have a property called oninput that is calling a function that is checking the values when the input is changed.

```
<input id="eMail_repeat" type="email" name="email_addr_repeat" title="Repeat your email address" placeholder="example@mail.com" required oninput="check(this)" />
```

Since you don't have that on your first input, the value is never checked again after you edit just the first input.

**Edit:**

Both inputs need `oninput=check()`

And the JavaScript to make it work:

```
   function check() { 
       var email = document.getElementById('eMail');
       var emailRepeat = document.getElementById('eMail_repeat');

       if (email.value != emailRepeat.value) { 
           emailRepeat.setCustomValidity('The two email addresses must match.'); 
       } else { 
           // input is valid -- reset the error message 
           emailRepeat.setCustomValidity(''); 
       } 
  }
```

I would move the variables email and emailRepeat into an onload function for the page so you aren't setting them every time someone types a letter in an input. But it will work like this.

Comment: So is it just the case of having to add required oninput="check(this)" to the first input?

Comment: No. That won't work because of the way the function is written. Give me a second to mess with it and I will see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Great stuff, that worked perfect. Thanks sooooo much.

Comment: It is better to use 'onblur' instead of 'oninput' - so the validatiion takes place after input is finished.